# Call to undefined function App\Providers\studly_case() after upgrade to Laravel 6.0.x

Tags: php, laravel, function, laravel-6, laravel-upgrade

As I mentioned in the question, I just upgraded the Laravel version of my project from 5.8.* to 6.0.*.

Now I am getting the below error:

```
In AppServiceProvider.php line 32:
Call to undefined function App\Providers\studly_case()
```

Is Laravel supposed to throw error in it's own core file ? I was invoking the following command when I got this error, so I suppose this happens with any artisan command:

```
php artisan list
```

I saw in docs, that the new function is `Str::studly` from `Str` class file. Is it ok to change in the `AppServiceProvider.php` ?

Comment: I think it was renamed to studly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the [Laravel 6.x docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-studly-case), I just discovered that the function for converting the string's current case to studly case is moved to `Illuminate\Support\Str` class, and named as `studly()`.

So I added that dependency and then replaced the `studly_case()` to `Str::studly()` in `AppServiceProvider.php`, and then was able to run the `artisan` commands just like before.

I wasn't sure that changing `AppServiceProvider.php` is standard way or not, but it did worked so I am posting the answer here, that way it'll help anyone else facing the same issue.